# How do I stop the navigation bar from creating an extra row?

Tags: html, css, web

I looked at another answer and it didn't help that much. I'm quite new to HTML so I was wondering if I could get some help. As you'll see on my http://toucanandbutterfly.uk/ if you resize the window, at a certain point the end buttons jump a row, which I really don't want. any help?

```
<nav><ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="home.html">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="PhotoLibrary.html">Photo Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="Policies.html">Policies</a></li>
            <li><a href="Information.html">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="WhereToFindUs.html">Where to Find us</a></li>
            <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        </ul></nav>
```

is the HTML, the CSS is:

```
.mainHeader nav {
        background: #97e41b;
        font-size: 1.143em;
        height: 160px;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }

.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.mainHeader nav li {
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    background: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: none !important;
}

.mainHeader nav li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;

    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Sorry, I don't know which particular piece I need.

Comment: You should post the relevant piece of code so people can see what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

You may either want to fix the width, or transform the nav object to a block element and work with overflow.

```
<nav>
  <a class="active" href="home.html">Home Page</a>
  <a href="PhotoLibrary.html">Photo Library</a>
  <a href="Policies.html">Policies</a>
  <a href="Information.html">Information</a>
  <a href="WhereToFindUs.html">Where to Find us</a>
  <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="Blog.html">Blog</a>
</nav>
```

and

```
body, #mainHeader {        min-width:        1000px }
nav {                      display:          block;
                           overflow:         visible;
                           text-align:       center;
                           word-spacing:     22px }
#mainHeader nav a.active { background-color: lime }
```

Further there is a lot of major errors in your code, so aside from your obvious problem, I advise to pull it trough validator.nu a couple of times.